# Trigger on database using a web application and a winform application

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

Situation:
I have a web application which shows errors and where you can accept those error messages. I also have a service, which checks errors from a system and sets the error messages in the database.
When I accept an error in the web application, i would like the service to know which error message has been accepted, so that it can do some other actions.

My guess is that this could be done through some sort of trigger, but i can't figure out how.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
It can be done through a service broker and an SQLDependency.

My solution came from the following website: [Dream in Code](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/156991-using-sqldependency-to-monitor-sql-database-changes/)